# Collision Detection

Tags: actionscript-3, collision-detection

i am working on a project that needs some collision detection.
i have 7 objects and it should check collide for each others.

i looked collision detection kit by Corey O'Neil, but cant figure it out.

collision group i have to learn, yes.

Comment: i figure it out, i can get colliding object's names. now i have to adjust overlapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should understand your needs.

**hitTestObject** method will work fine if you have no FPS drop and object is static or have small speed.

Else you better to use one of Physics Engine or [CDK](http://code.google.com/p/collisiondetectionkit/) like a Box2D for correct collision detection and make your Update method fixed timestep.

Comment: box2d is complicated to learn, i will take my chances with CDK

Comment: box2d can be simple but flash is not ready yet, i have done my job with cdk. i cant take my time, dont have time.

Answer (score 0):

Try `hitTestObject()`

```
if(object1.hitTestObject(object2))
{
    // collision was detected, do stuff here
}
```

Comment: i guess, this is not ganna work if i want to pixel by pixel collision. i remember i have tried this.